# Google Apps Script development with Cloud9 IDE

Tags: typescript, google-apps-script, visual-studio-code, cloud9-ide

Has anyone successfully setup Cloud9 as an IDE for google apps script development, specifically for JS files.

I have been able to setup VSCode and clasp -- and that works well -- as described at these locations.

- [Google app script desktop ide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48983003/google-app-script-desktop-ide)
- https://yagisanatode.com/2019/04/01/working-with-google-apps-script-in-visual-studio-code-using-clasp/
- https://github.com/google/clasp/blob/master/docs/typescript.md

I want to use Cloud9 for the portability of it and not be forced into VSCode on a desktop only.

The problem is - if I use the above setup with Cloud9 (basically npm install @types/google-apps-script and also clasp) - autocomplete support only works for *.ts files and not for *.js files. When using Cloud9, *.js or *.ts are both successfully pushed as .gs to the google cloud platform but I am not sure why JS cannot leverage autocomplete on Cloud9 while VSCode is somehow able to (for both *.js and *.ts).

Any help is welcome. I hope I am not the only one needing a cloud IDE for google apps script for JS files.

Thank you.

===========Summary TS setup from google's page, need something similar for JS on Cloud9============

Prerequisites

Ensure you have upgraded to clasp's version >= 1.5.0

`clasp -v`

Install TypeScript definitions for Apps Script in your project's folder.

`npm i -S @types/google-apps-script`

Create a file called tsconfig.json to enable TypeScript features:

````
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["esnext"],
    "experimentalDecorators": true
  }
}```
````

Comment: Has this ever been resolved?